# Find instance of word in files and change it to the filename

Tags: sed

I have files named like A1.V5.76.txt and B5.CV.PH.txt containing text like:

> Here is the name of the file filename

I would like to change the word filename in the text to the actual filename (except for the extension.)

For example, the above would read:

> Here is the name of the file A1.V5.76

I have tried the following code that I've edited and repurposed from an old project where I was passing the directory name as a variable but nothing happens:

```
for file in *.melanie; sed -i "s/filename/$file/g"; done
```

I apologize for the less-than-great code. I am still learning.

Comment: You're missing `do` between `;` and `sed`. You should've been getting a syntax error for that instead of just "nothing happens" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a little bit problems in your command, you can modify it as followed,

```
for file in *.melanie;do sed -i "s/filename/$file/g" $file; done
```

Brief explanation,

- You forgot the word `do` for your for loop
- You forgot the input file for the `sed` command, so add `$file` back.

Modified these two should be good to go.

Comment: Derp! Thank you! Shouldn't be writing code when I'm half asleep! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Following awk should help you in same.

```
awk '{sub("filename",FILENAME);print}' A1.V5.76.txt
```

So above will substitute string "filename" will name of the Input_file. If you are happy with above command's result then you could run following command to make change into Input_file itself by doing following.

```
awk '{sub("filename",FILENAME);print}' A1.V5.76.txt > temp_file && mv temp_file A1.V5.76.txt
```

***EDIT:*** In case you want to pass multiple files and their extension is *.txt then following may help you in same.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  if(val){
   close(val);
   close("temp_file");
   system("mv temp_file " val)
};
  val=FILENAME
}
{
  sub("filename",FILENAME);
  print > "temp_file"
}
END{
  if(val){
   close("temp_file");
   system("mv temp_file " val)
}
}
' *.txt
```

Comment: @MelanieShebel, you should just pass any filename and if it has string filename then it should fly then.

Comment: @MelanieShebel, check my EDIT solution, which will take care of all .txt files in a directory, let me know on same.