# Use sed find ID in txt file and use ID to rename file

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed, wget

Using wget, a webpage is downloaded as a .txt file. This file saved is named using part of the url of the webpage, eg. `wget http://www.example.com/page/12345/ -O 12345.txt`, for convenience.

I am running commands from a shell script `.sh` file, as it can execute multiple commands, one line at time, eg.

After a file is downloaded, I use sed to parse for text / characters I want to keep. Part of the text I want includes `blah blah Product ID a5678`.

What I want is to use sed to find `a5678` and use this to rename the file 12345.txt to a5678.txt.

```
# script.sh
wget http://www.example.com/page/12345/ -O 12345.txt
sed -i '' 's/pattern/replace/g' 12345.txt
sed command to find a5678 # in line blah blah Product ID a5678 
some more sed commands
mv 12345.txt a5678.txt (or use a variable $var.txt)?
```

How do I do this?

I may also want to use this same ID `a5678` and create a folder with the same name `a5678`. Hence the .txt file is inside the folder like so `/a5678/a5678.txt`.

```
mkdir a5678 (or mkdir $var)? && cd a5678
```

I've searched for answers for half a day, but can't find any. The closest I found is
[Find instance of word in files and change it to the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46576788/find-instance-of-word-in-files-and-change-it-to-the-filename) but it is the exact opposite of what I want. I've also thought about using variables eg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command but I don't know how to save the found characters as a variable.

Very much look forward to some help! Thank you! I am on a Mac running Sierra.

Comment: Unless you are _replacing_ characters in the files, I might just use `grep` instead, cutting the results to extract the strings I need for renaming. Or switch to perl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to minimize, so fit this into your logic.

```
in=12345.txt
out=$( grep ' Product ID ' $in | sed 's/.* Product ID \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/' )
mkdir -p $out
mv $in $out/$out.txt
```

Comment: a couple of mods I might suggest:  add a `-m 1` flag to the `grep` (to prevent multiple matches), and add an `if [ $out ]; then` clause around the `mkdir` and `mv` commands, so if the string isn't found, you don't get odd behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! With your inspiration, I solved my problem by (without using grep):

```
in=12345
out=$(sed -n '/pattern/ s/.*ID *//p' $in.txt)
mv $in.txt $out.txt
cd ..
mv $in $out
```

Comment: And I think I finally figured out the `-n` - `/p` combo, lol. Thanks. :)